# Implementing a writeBit method in Java

Tags: java, encoding, binary, huffman-code, dataoutputstream

So I know that in Java you cannot write out individual bits to a file and that you have to use writeByte. I have some understanding that there is a way to implement a writeBit method that makes use of writeByte by calling writeByte once 8 'bits' are concatenated together. I was hoping to implement this like:

```
public void writeBit(char bit) {
    try {
    //functionality here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

But I just cannot seem to get started. I understand that I should probably have some attribute that keeps track of how many bits I have concatenated, but other than that I'm lost as to how to implement this.

I guess my big question here is how can I continuously call writeBit without losing my concatenated String of bits, and what would an implementation of writeBit look like, if it were to make use of writeByte?

As a side note, I am using a DataOutputStream here if this was not clear.

Comment: You don't just need to keep track of *how many* bits have been provided, but *what* bits have been provided (so far). Does that help?

Comment: It's just buffering. You have to buffer up to one byte, and keep track of which bit you are currently up to.

Comment: You should look into instance variables.  Also I'm not sure why your `bit` parameter is a char type.  A bit can only be true or false, so it should be a boolean type.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes I see what you're getting at there

Comment: You can only write to a file in bytes. How do you write only 3 bits to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed a couple people have talked about using two instance variables, one to store the byte as you add bits to it and another to keep track of how many bits have been added so far.  While this is a perfectly good way to do it, I'd like to show why you don't need a second instance variable.

## Theory

There's no need to keep track of how many bits have been added so far.  The only piece of information we need is "has the byte been filled yet?".  Instead of initializing your byte to 0, try initializing it to a value of 1.  Then each time you add a bit, shift the bits of the byte to the left one place (using the bitshift operator `<<`), and then add the new bit in the rightmost place.

In practice, it would look something like this, where `X` is the newly added bit:

Initialize the byte to a value of 1: `00000001`

To insert a new bit, shift the bits to the left: `00000010`

And add the new bit `X` in the rightmost place: `0000001X`

Shift left: `000001X0`

Add the new bit: `000001XX`

Eventually, you'd have 7 bits written from your method and the leftmost bit would be `1`: `1XXXXXXX`

So in your method, you can check to see if the leftmost bit is set every time it's called.  If it is, then you know you're ready to write the byte to the file on this iteration.  You would start by doing the same thing, shifting left and then adding the new bit, so now you have `XXXXXXXX`.  Then you would write the now-full byte to the file, and then reset the byte to a value of 1 so the cycle can start over again.

## Writing the code

First you'll need an instance variable to keep track of these bits.  It will need to be type byte, and I'll just call it `buffer`.

To shift the bits to the left one place, we can use the bitshift operator, `<<`.  And, to make our lives even easier, there's even a bitshift assignment operator, `<<=`, so we can perform the bitshift and assign the new value back to the variable all in one operation.  This leaves us with:

```java
buffer <<= 1;
```

The next thing we'll need to do is add the new bit.  If you OR a value with 1, the rightmost bit will be set, and the rest of the bits will be unaffected.  If you OR a value with 0, none of the bits are affected.  We can use this trick to only set the rightmost bit if the new bit is a 1 (The `|=` is the OR assignment operator):

```java
buffer |= bit ? 1 : 0;
```

Then, the last piece of this code is writing the if statement to check if the leftmost bit is set.  If it is, then when we AND it with `10000000`, we will get `10000000`.  If not, we will get `00000000`.  `10000000` is `128` in decimal (or `-128`, or `256`, all will work), so our expression is:

```java
(buffer & 128) == 128
```

## Result

Putting all these pieces together, we get:

```java
// Notice bit is type boolean
public void writeBit(boolean bit) {
    // If the leftmost bit in buffer is set:
    if ((buffer & 128) == 128) {

        // Shift all the bits in buffer to the left 1 place
        buffer <<= 1;

        // Add the new bit in the rightmost place
        buffer |= bit ? 1 : 0;

        // Write the now-full byte to the file
        // I'm just calling your DataOutputStream "dos" here
        try {
            dos.writeByte(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        // Reset buffer to a value of 1
        buffer = 1;
    } else {
        // Shift all the bits in buffer to the left 1 place
        buffer <<= 1;

        // Add the new bit in the rightmost place
        buffer |= bit ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs testing and correction. buffer needs to be larger than a byte, in which case your idea works if you write out the least significant byte before resetting. 0b10000000 != 256. Testing a byte & 256 is meaningless.

Comment: @Passerby You are correct, the test should be 128, not 256.  Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I have updated the answer.  I have tested the code and it does indeed work as intended.  Please see my theory section for why `buffer` does not need to be larger than a byte.  If you are not convinced, feel free to copy the code and test it yourself.

Comment: The correction is enough, it needed to be larger than a byte if you wanted to test 256 not 128, that's all.

Comment: That's a very clever implementation!

Comment: @Passerby Actually, interestingly enough, in my testing I have noticed that 256 also works.  This is because 256 is an int, so in order to perform the & operation, the JVM promotes buffer to an int as well.  Normally, it fills all but the most significant byte with 0's, but when the number is negative, it has to fill it with 1's because negative numbers are in two's complement.  Since the MSB happens to be the sign bit, effectively this bit gets copied over to the next significant bit when buffer gets promoted to an int.  It was a mistake at first, but interestingly it does work using 256.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class with two instance variables, the first with the bits that you have accumulated so far, and the second with how many bits you have accumulated. Use the shift and or operations to insert a bit into the buffer (initialized to zero), and increment the number of bits. Once you have eight bits, write the buffer, then zero out the buffer and the count.

At the end you will need to flush any remaining bits if the count is not zero by writing the buffer to a byte, even though it contains less than eight bits. The format of the sequence of bits needs to be able to deal with this eventuality, unless it assures that a multiple of eight bits is always written.